# How to get json data values for clicked buttons and uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I get json data for only clicked buttons and uploaded files if any, as of now I am getting all the clicked/non-clicked button values in one case and getting uploaded files(with fakepath, like: `C:\\fakepath\\test.txt`) in another case in json format. I have created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/w70zkfod/), please help me to get clicked buttons data and uploaded files(i.e names) only in json format.

```js
(function() {
  var buttonValue = {};
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("input[type=button]" && "input[type=file]").each(function($i) {
      var name = $(this).attr('name')
      buttonValue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(buttonValue)); //I am getting my uploaded file fake path like: C:\\fakepath\\test.txt. not giving the clicked button values in json
  });
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='button1' class='button' name='firstButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' value='button2' class='button' name='secondButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' value='button3' class='button' name='thirdButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='file' name='file' value='file upload' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'>
```

Comment: You can't use `&&` inside `$(...)`. The way to use multiple selectors is to separate them with comma in the selector string: `$("input[type=button], input[type=file]")`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, one issue is resolved(getting <input type="file"> after adding comma(,)but one more is that, I am getting all clicked/non-clicked data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/w70zkfod/1/

```
(function(){
    var buttonValue = {};
    $("input[type=button]").click(function(){
        var name =$(this).attr('name')     
        buttonValue[name]=$(this).val();
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("input[type=file]").each(function($i){
            var name =$(this).attr('name')     
            buttonValue[name]=$(this).val();
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(buttonValue));
    });
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to select multiple elements is by separating them with comma in the selector.

```js
(function() {
  var buttonValue = {};
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("input[type=button], input[type=file]").each(function($i) {
      var name = $(this).attr('name')
      buttonValue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(buttonValue));
  });
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='button1' class='button' name='firstButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' value='button2' class='button' name='secondButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' value='button3' class='button' name='thirdButton' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='file' name='file' value='file upload' />
<br>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'>
```

Buttons don't remember whether they were clicked, maybe you should use checkboxes instead. Then you could use `$(":checkbox:checked")` to select the ones that have been clicked.